# Не приходит сообщение recvfrom

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    client.sendto("AABBCC".encode(encoding="utf-8"), (target_host, target_port))
    data, adr = client.recvfrom(4096)
    print(data, adr)
```

Comment: Добавьте пример и сервера

Comment: это же udp, я просто отправляю сообщение и принимаю его, зачем тут сервер?

Comment: **1)** вы писали про recvfrom которого нет в коде **2)** рекомендуется в вопросе приводить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Если сервер запущен на локалхосте и обращение идёт туда, то, очевидно, пакет не мог потеряться или отброситься фаерволом. Тогда проблема действительно в сервере. Лучше приведите его код.